# trying to simplify equation to fullest

Tags: boolean-algebra

I've got an equation down to $F=BA+BC +\bar{A}\bar{C}$ and according to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=a52797be9f91295a27b14cb751198ae3) it can simplified to $(\bar{A} + \bar{C}) + B$. What's the next steps? I tried using de Morgan's law and not sure it helped.

Comment: Try to restrict to one question power post while showing your effort

Comment: I think you misread the result.

Comment: @StefanPerko so it can't be simplified any further?

Comment: Who's responsible for the -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a derivation for the actual result:

$BA + BC + \bar{A}\bar{C} = (B(A+C))+\overline{A+C} = (B+\overline{A+C})((A+C)+\overline{A+C}) = \overline{A+C}+B$

I used:

- Distributivity of "$\cdot$ over $+$" and DeMorgan (for "NOR")
- Distributivity of "$+$ over $\cdot$"
- $P + \bar{P} = 1$ and $P\cdot 1 = P$

and some Commutativity and Associativity.

Comment: Is $\overline{A+C} $ the same as $\bar{A}+\bar{C}$?

Comment: @leftandright No, it is not. You know the deMorgan laws, don't you? It's $\overline{A+C} = \bar{A}\bar{C}$ and $\overline{AC} = \bar{A}+\bar{C}$. Using an example: "It is not raining or snowing" (meaning there is no rain and there is no snow) has a different meaning than "It is not raining or it is not snowing."